# Bootstrap: button with image inside, remove visible button parts

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html:

```
<br/><br/><center>
  <button>
    <img src="https://www.abeautifulsite.net/uploads/2014/09/menu-icon.png?width=600&key=4bc015049071e7e16c61decfe5eca75cd081194e39a9e235b780ce644ef7e6ce"/>
  </button>
</center>
```

and css:

```
button  {
  width: 80px;
  height: 90px;
}

img  {
  width: 80px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

which results in [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPjVrv). There are edges of the button visible. Is there a way to make them invisible/expand the image to all of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it as:

```css
button {
  width: 80px;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<br/><br/>
<center>
  <button>
    <img src="https://www.abeautifulsite.net/uploads/2014/09/menu-icon.png?width=600&key=4bc015049071e7e16c61decfe5eca75cd081194e39a9e235b780ce644ef7e6ce"/>
  </button>
</center>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don’t really need Bootstrap to do this. Here is a solution without:

```css
button  {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

img  {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<br/><br/><center>
  <button>
    <img src="https://www.abeautifulsite.net/uploads/2014/09/menu-icon.png?width=600&key=4bc015049071e7e16c61decfe5eca75cd081194e39a9e235b780ce644ef7e6ce"/>
  </button>
</center>
```

And here is a solution with the version 3 of Bootstrap you tried to include (URL in your codepen gives a 404), taken from [their documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#buttons-options):

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

img  {
  width: 80px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<br/><br/><center>
  <button class="btn btn-link">
    <img src="https://www.abeautifulsite.net/uploads/2014/09/menu-icon.png?width=600&key=4bc015049071e7e16c61decfe5eca75cd081194e39a9e235b780ce644ef7e6ce"/>
  </button>
</center>
```

Comment: It wasn't me, have upvoted you. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @parsecer: That wasn’t meant for you. Don’t worry. :)

Either there is no way to know who downvoted or I don’t know how to see that information. I just feel that if something I post deserves a downvote, then I could learn something in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your css the `border` property and set it to 0

```
button {
  width: 80px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 0;
}
```